# Java WSDL Web Service Getting the client certificate

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a SOAP webservice made in Java, running on Oracle Weblogic. And I need to get the certificate which is supposed to be provided by the client connecting, and extract some information (IssuerDN). How would I go about this?

Edit: I think the 1st thing I am stuck on, is how do I get the input-stream/connection? Then how would I get the certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends what implementation you are running. I some cases the request certificate may be put on the SOAPMessageContext. If that is the case you can implement a SOAPhandler to get hold of the certificate used in the request.

For example, in the IBM Websphere´s Axis2 based implementation of JAX-WS the following code will retrieve the certificate:

```
public X509Certificate getRequestCertificate(SOAPMessageContext aMessageContext) {
    return ((java.security.cert.X509Certificate) aMessageContext.get("com.ibm.xml.soapsec.RequestCert"));
}
```

Notice, be aware of the following. The code above may **not** be supported by the vendor of the web service container implementation.

Comment: By Implementation do you mean Axis 2/JAX-WS ? As that's what i'm using.  However I'm still very confused as to how to get the cert!

Comment: The Axis2 engine is bundled in many application servers. What you can try is to write a SOAP handler which dumps (print out) all SOAPMessageContext´s attributes. Hopefully you may find the certificate or the principal on the message context.